# Error when embedding model data into a javascript variable in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm having a hard time trying to parse data from JSON into rails.

Anyways I'm trying to create and display markers into a google map, but I keep getting the following syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected ')'
...e_javascript raw '@job_json' -).to_s); _erbout.concat "\";\n"
```

`map.js.erb`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mapEl = $('#map');
  var optimized = !mapEl.data('test-env');

  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      disableDefaultUI: false
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map'
    }
  },
  function() {
    var jobJSON = "<%= escape_javascript raw @job_json -%>"; // ERROR MESSAGE HERE
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
        // "lat": 50.827016,
        // "lng": 4.372516,
        "address": 'job.location', // data I want to display on the map
      }
    ], { optimized: optimized }); // true or false
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.map.centerOn({
      lat: 50.1351162,
      lng: 2.8922343
    });
    handler.getMap().setZoom(6);

    if(!optimized) {
      // Add container for the markers for easy iteration
      // by doing $("#markers img").
      var myOverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

      myOverlay.draw = function () {
        this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markers';
      };

      myOverlay.setMap(handler.getMap());
    }
  });
});
```

Code `JobsController`

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:edit, :update]
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @jobs = Job.all
    # @jobs = current_user.jobs.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @job_json = @job.to_json(only: [:location, :title, :id])
  end

  def new
    @jobs = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
    @job.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, success: 'Job wiki was created!' }
        format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in the asset pipeline (that is, in the `app/assets` folder) do not have access to the instance variables defined in the controller the way that your views do. This is why you are getting an error. You will have to find some other way to get `@job_json` from Rails to JavaScript.

Since you are looking to get information on only a single job, you might consider including it in your page somewhere as a data attribute, like so:

**show.html.erb**

```
...

<div id='map' data-job='<%= @job_json %>'>
</div>

...
```

**maps.js.erb**

```
...

var jobJSON = $('#map').data('job');

...
```

Obviously, this won't work as nicely if you ever need to transfer a great many records to JavaScript because it would require a great many data attributes (or one long one). In that case, AJAX might serve you better. But for only one record, this method works just fine.

You might also consider looking into the [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem, which makes your Ruby variables available to your JavaScript assets.

---

## Update

I have looked through your application, the [Google Maps for Rails README](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), and around the web in general, and found a method that might work for you given that you are displaying many jobs at once. I implemented it myself in your code, and while it may need some tweaking to get it just how you like it, it is functional.

### Step 1: Install Geocoder

The [Geocoder](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem pairs well with Google Maps for Rails because it converts addresses or place names to coordinates. Google Maps for Rails used to have this functionality on its own, but somewhere along the line it [forfeited the responsibility](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Why-but-why%3F).

**Gemfile**

```
...

gem 'geocoder'

...
```

**Console**

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToJobs latitude:float longitude:float
$ rake db:migrate
```

**Job.rb**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  geocoded_by :location

  ...

  after_validation :geocode
end
```

### Step 2: Re-Seed the Database

The `jobs` table has latitude and longitude columns now, but they're empty. The quickest way to get that `after_validation :geocode` callback to fill them is to just overwrite your current data with a clean database and re-seed. You may need to fix your seed code in `seeds.rb` first; it gave me errors over a missing comma and an invalid datetime.

**Console**

```
$ rake db:schema:load
$ rake db:seed
```

### Step 3: Get the Map Working on the Job `show` Page

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@job) do |job, marker|
    marker.lat job.latitude
    marker.lng job.longitude
    marker.infowindow job.location
  end
end
```

In the JavaScript, replace the `$(document).ready`-executing function with a callable one...

**maps.js.erb**

```
function drawMap(mapId, marker_json) {
    var mapEl = $('#' + mapId);
    var optimized = !mapEl.data('test-env');

    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap(
        {
            provider: {
                disableDefaultUI: false
            },
            internal: {
                id: 'map'
            }
        },
        function() {
            markers = handler.addMarkers(
                marker_json,
                { optimized: optimized } // true or false
            );
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();

            if (!optimized) {
                // Add container for the markers for easy iteration
                // by doing $('#markers img').
                var myOverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

                myOverlay.draw = function () {
                    this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markers';
                };

                myOverlay.setMap(handler.getMap());
            }
      });
}
```

...and then call it from your view, where you *can* access your controller's instance variables.

**show.html.erb**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function initialize() {
      drawMap('map', <%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

...
```

### Step 4: Get the Map Working on the User `show` Page

This is basically the same thing as Step 3, but with multiple jobs.

**users_controller.rb**

```
...

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @jobs = @user.jobs

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@jobs) do |job, marker|
    marker.lat job.latitude
    marker.lng job.longitude
    marker.infowindow job.location
  end
end

...
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function initialize() {
      drawMap('map', <%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

...
```

I hope that this helps you. As I mentioned, it worked when I tried it, and I do believe I covered everything I changed...

Comment: Hey man, well I'm actually passing it a whole bunch of jobs really. On the index view I want to display all the markers in the map, but I also would like display each individual marker for a each particular job. I updated the code, but markers are still not displaying. [Git repo](https://github.com/dantesolis/jobtracker/tree/map-markers) && [AppLink](https://ds-jobtracker.herokuapp.com)

Comment: @D_S I updated my answer to suit your requirements and the recommendations of the Google Maps for Rails gem. Hopefully the new code will work better for you.

Comment: thanks I had thought about using the gem but decided against cause I was afraid that if I did I was no longer be able to add ```@job``` via Ajax. But I'm going to implement what you recommend as soon as I get home.